# « Épépiner » pour les pépins. Et pour les épines?

Tags: vocabulaire, verbes, botanique

Il y a le verbe *épépiner* pour l'action d'enlever les pépins d'un fruit.

Je cherche désespérément s'il existe un mot pour l'action d'enlever les épines (<strike>d'une tige de rose par exemple</strike> ← Ben non, les roses ont des aiguillons ! Merci Knu ! :) ou s'il faut juste garder l'expression « enlever les épines ».

Comment: _Et les épines, à quoi servent-elles ?_

Comment: En passant les rosiers ont des aiguillons (pas des épines).

Comment: «[La rose dit:] “Quant aux grosses bêtes, je ne crains rien, j'ai mes griffes.” / Et elle montrait naïvement ses quatre épines. Puis elle ajouta: “Ne traîne pas comme ça, c'est agaçant. Tu as décidé de partir. Va-t'en.” / Car elle ne voulait pas qu'il la vît pleurer. C'était une fleur tellement orgueilleuse...» —Antoine de Saint-Exupéry, _Le Petit Prince_

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A mon avis, il n'y a pas vraiment de verbe autre que « enlever les épines » — si c'était le cas, l'expression « enlever une épine du pied » n'existerait probablement pas.

Sinon, on pourrait envisager *désépiner*, j'imagine (*dépiner* étant sans doute à éviter).

Edit: merci à Knu de me rappeler que [Google Books](http://www.google.com/search?q=d%C3%A9s%C3%A9piner&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) existe. J'y trouve un
[article de Francine Gerhard-Krait sur le préfixe dé(s)-¹](http://books.google.com/books?id=S_7AElwajSQC&pg=PA75&dq=%22d%C3%A9s%C3%A9piner%22&hl=en&ei=rfCHTrOHNJCKhQfMsMWKDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CCsQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22d%C3%A9s%C3%A9piner%22&f=false). L'auteur y mentionne que *désépiner*, **s'il existait**, conviendrait aux roses mais pas aux pieds. l'exemple de la *poussière dans l'oeil* de la page précédente est aussi similaire — on ne peut pas pour autant *dépoussiérer l'oeil*.

¹ 
<sub>Francine Gerhard-Krait. *Enlever une poussière* vs *dépoussiérer* : le préfixe *dé(s)-* fait le ménage. In *Kognitive Linguistik und Neurowissenschaften: Referate des gleichnamigen EUCOR-Kolloquiums im Herbst 1998 in Freiburg*. Ed. Georges Kleiber, 1999.</sub>

Comment: +1 pour dépiner!

Comment: Vu que l'outil des floriculteur pour enlever les épines s'appelle un Enlève-épines, je pense qu'il n'y a pas de terme spécifique.

Comment: Il est vrai que "Merci, tu m'as désépiné le pied !" ne sonne pas très bien et on a bien fait de garder l'expression initiale.

Comment: @SylvainPeyronnet Merci, ça confirme bien la réponse de Joubarc mais les floriculteurs n'ont donc pas d'enlève-aiguillons du coup suite au commentaire de Knu ?

Comment: @LudoMC Très bonne remarque; j'aurais eu envie de dire que non car le propre de l'aiguillon c'est que c'est une excroissance superficielle non vascularisée, qu'on peut donc enlever à la main. Mais en fait je viens de trouver une définition de l'enlève-épines (ou épineuse également) qui dit "Elle sert à enlever les aiguillons sur les tiges des roses"... A vrai dire pour enlever une vraie epine (et pas un aiguillon), il faut sans doute un couteau car l'épine est vascularisée et fibreuse.

Comment: Apparemment *dépiner* existe en picard. Heureusement ça n'a pas le sens de sexuellement défourailler.

Comment: @Knu Tu *déconnes*, là. Très étymologiquement.

Answer (score 4):

Ce serait *désaiguillonner* qui est par exemple [cité](http://books.google.fr/books?id=1FQMAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA566&dq=%22d%C3%A9saiguillonner%22) dans un dictionnaire FR/EN de 1833.
Mais attention ça n'a rien à voir avec *aiguiller* et *aiguillonner* (bien qu'une plante munie d'aiguillons est dite *aiguillonnée*, le [sens communément compris](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/aiguillonner) est tout autre).

Ainsi on pourrait comprendre *dissuader*, donc je te conseillerais plutôt d'utiliser **enlever les aiguillons** tout simplement.

Comment: Je ne peux pas et [citer](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/4432/1514) et moissoyer, mais effectivement, ça ne semble pas être une solution (et on aura compris que je ne suis **pas** partisan de « laisse tomber, dis-le autrement »).

Answer (score 2):

Un terme technique proche trouvé dans Le Littré, qui pourrait faire une 'trouvaille' littéraire (ou un exemple tiré par les cheveux) :

> **dépingler** : Enlever les épingles d'une toile tendue par les bords.

A un enfant s'extrayant d'un buisson d'épineux, son père passementier :

> "Viens là que je te dépingle!"

La traduction française de l'anglais [unpin](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?source=anglais&query=unpin) ne renvoie aucun *dépinglé* comme usage courant.

Les *épines, épingles, échardes **s'enlèvent*** donc sans bruit (sans jargon particulier), mais parfois avec des cris de douleur.

Comment: +1 parce que c'est le plus invraisemblable pour [ma collection](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/4432/1514), et aussi parce que c'est bien écrit. (Outre que ça répond parfaitement à la question.)